Pynput - проблема с отслеживанием нажатий клавиш клавиатуры
Когда отслеживаю нажатия клавиш, все работает нормально, но стоит сменить раскладку клавиатуры - то отслеживание клавиш идет на предыдущей раскладки. То-бишь если тыкаю на 'Y' на английской раскладке - то принимается английская, сменяю раскладку на русскую и тыкаю на 'Н' (русскую) то принимается английская Y. Как решить проблему?
Вот код:
from pynput.keyboard import *

def press(key):
    try:
        print('Клавига {0} нажата'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('Спец.клавиша {0} нажата'.format(key))

with Listener(on_press=press) as listener:
    listener.join()


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример. начните с формулировки заголовка.

@aleksandrbarakin, изменил
